# posting to tumblr home page and added page

Tags: html, tumblr, posting

I am trying to post to a tumblr page on the both the home page and an added page, I would like the post to appear on both pages. I tried tagging the photo and adding the url of the added page to the post but it won't work. My added page does not give me the option to change the layout from standard to redirect. The only options are standard and customize. I also tried adding tagged to the added page and the name of the added page to the post as tag but also did not work.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with simply creating one as a blog post and using the same content to create the additional page (so two content sources in effect).

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by 'added page' but if you tag a post with a certain tag, you can bring up that post on a separate page with by going to yoururl.tumblr.com/tagged/tag . Alternatively you can go to the posts permalink page.